# React object not getting with updated redux store value

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a constant `totalRowsSelected` which I am trying to console in `Processor` function and inside `processorColumnConfig` Object in `handleOnChange` method. The issue is that it is printing the right value outside the `processorColumnConfig` Object but when used inside the `processorColumnConfig` Object, it is always printing the initial value which is a blank array.
PLEASE ctrl + F `totalRowsSelected` and you'll understand what I am trying to say.
Sorry for the long code.

Additional Info: I am using the react-table and passing the `processorColumnConfig` as a ColumnConfig prop.

Source code below:

```
import { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import {
  getTempData,
  saveTempData,
  updateTableData,
  updateRowID,
  toggleData,
  toggleColumn,
  getCurrencyData,
  setSelectedRows,
  processCheckedData,
  setProcessedDataResponse,
  clearSelectedRows,
  setDeleteRows,
  deleteRows,
  setRowID,
  setSelectedView,
} from '../../actions/processor/processor.actions';
import { type, pathOr, clone, omit, lens, prop, set, assoc, pick, pluck, isEmpty } from 'ramda';
import ConfirmationModal from './ConfirmationModal';
import UpdateTempDB from './UpdateTempDB';
import ModifyCellData from './ModifyCellData';
import FundID from './FundID';
import { mockData } from '../../constants/FilesConstants';
import './Processor.scss';
import DatePickerComponent from './DatePickerComponent';

const tableColumnConfig = {
  key: 'dealsExposureTable',
  sortBy: 'dealDate',
  sortOrder: 'descending',
  pageSize: 10,
  total: 30,
  page: 1,
};
const Processor = () => {
  const selectedView = useSelector((state) => state.pcPerformance.processor.tempStorageData.selectedView);
  const processorColumnConfig = [
    {
      Header: 'id',
      id: 'id',
      accessor: 'Id',
      width: 10,
    },
    {
      Header: '',
      id: 'currentRowID',
      accessor: 'currentRowID',
      width: 0,
    },
    {
      Header: '',
      id: 'prevRowID',
      accessor: 'prevRowID',
      width: 0,
    },
    {
      Header: 'Fund Name',
      id: 'fundName',
      accessor: 'FundName',
      sticky: 'left',
      width: 160,
    },
    {
      Header: '',
      id: 'IsDuplicate',
      accessor: 'IsDuplicate',
      Cell: (row) => row.value && <External />,
      width: 20,
    },
    {
      Header: 'Fund ID',
      id: 'FundId',
      accessor: 'FundId',
      Cell: (row) => <FundID row={row} accessor={'FundId'} />,
      Filter: false,
      width: 96,
    },
    {
      Header: 'Currency',
      id: 'value_currency',
      accessor: (row) => {
        return (
          <Fragment key={row.Id}>
            <CurrencyDropdown rowId={row.Id} existingCurrency={row.CurrencyCode} />
          </Fragment>
        );
      },
      Filter: false,
      width: 160,
    },
    {
      Header: 'Total LP Commitment',
      id: 'lpCommitment',
      accessor: 'LPCommitment',
      Cell: (row) => {
        return (
          <div className="input_wraper">
            <Input
              type="text"
              value={type(row.value) === 'Object' ? row.value.value : row.value}
              onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value, 'LPCommitment', row.value, row.row.original.Id)}
              style={{ 'text-align': 'right' }}
            />
            {hasValidationError(row.value) && (
              <span id={`LPCommitment-${row.row.original.Id}`}>
                {row.value.SoftValidation && <Away />}
                {row.value.HardValidation && <Idle />}
                <Tooltip
                  title={row.value.ErrorMessage}
                  target={`LPCommitment-${row.row.original.Id}`}
                  position="bottom"
                />
              </span>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      },
      Filter: false,
      width: 160,
    },
    // <ModifyCellData row={row} accessor={'LPCommitment'}
    //                                  onCellChange = {handleOnChange} />
    {
      Header: 'Total Capital Called ',
      id: 'lpContribution',
      accessor: 'LPContribution',
      Cell: (row) => {
        return (
          <div className="input_wraper">
            <Input
              type="text"
              value={precise(type(row.value) === 'Object' ? row.value.value : row.value)}
              onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value, 'LPContribution', row.value, row.row.original.Id)}
              style={{ 'text-align': 'right' }}
            />
            {hasValidationError(row.value) && (
              <span id={`LPContribution-${row.row.original.Id}`}>
                {row.value.SoftValidation && <Away />}
                {row.value.HardValidation && <Idle />}
                <Tooltip
                  title={row.value.ErrorMessage}
                  target={`LPContribution-${row.row.original.Id}`}
                  position="bottom"
                />
              </span>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      },
      Filter: false,
      width: 160,
    },
    {
      Header: 'Total Distributions',
      id: 'lpDistribution',
      accessor: 'LPDistribution',
      Cell: (row) => {
        return (
          <div className="input_wraper">
            <Input
              type="text"
              value={precise(type(row.value) === 'Object' ? row.value.value : row.value)}
              onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value, 'LPDistribution', row.value, row.row.original.Id)}
              style={{ 'text-align': 'right' }}
            />
            {hasValidationError(row.value) && (
              <span id={`LPDistribution-${row.row.original.Id}`}>
                {row.value.SoftValidation && <Away />}
                {row.value.HardValidation && <Idle />}
                <Tooltip
                  title={row.value.ErrorMessage}
                  target={`LPDistribution-${row.row.original.Id}`}
                  position="bottom"
                />
              </span>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      },
      Filter: false,
      width: 160,
    },
    {
      Header: 'Unrealized Value',
      id: 'fundMarketValue',
      accessor: 'FundMarketValue',
      Cell: (row) => {
        return (
          <div className="input_wraper">
            <Input
              type="text"
              value={precise(type(row.value) === 'Object' ? row.value.value : row.value)}
              onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value, 'FundMarketValue', row.value, row.row.original.Id)}
              style={{ 'text-align': 'right' }}
            />
            {hasValidationError(row.value) && (
              <span id={`FundMarketValue-${row.row.original.Id}`}>
                {row.value.SoftValidation && <Away />}
                {row.value.HardValidation && <Idle />}
                <Tooltip
                  title={row.value.ErrorMessage}
                  target={`FundMarketValue-${row.row.original.Id}`}
                  position="bottom"
                />
              </span>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      },
      Filter: false,
      width: 160,
    },
    {
      Header: 'Net IRR',
      id: 'reportedIRR',
      accessor: 'ReportedIRR',
      Cell: (row) => {
        return (
          <div className="input_wraper">
            <Input
              type="text"
              value={type(row.value) === 'Object' ? precise(row.value.value) : precise(row.value)}
              onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value, 'ReportedIRR', row.value, row.row.original.Id)}
              style={{ 'text-align': 'right' }}
            />
            {hasValidationError(row.value) && (
              <span id={`ReportedIRR-${row.row.original.Id}`}>
                {row.value.SoftValidation && <Away />}
                {row.value.HardValidation && <Idle />}
                <Tooltip
                  title={row.value.ErrorMessage}
                  target={`ReportedIRR-${row.row.original.Id}`}
                  position="bottom"
                />
              </span>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      },
      Filter: false,
      width: 96,
    },
    {
      Header: 'Source ID',
      id: 'sourceId',
      accessor: 'SourceId',
      Cell: (row) => <FundID row={row} accessor={'SourceId'} />,
      Filter: false,
      width: 96,
    },
    {
      Header: 'Date Reported',
      id: 'dateReported',
      accessor: 'DateReported',
      Cell: (row) => {
        return (
          <Fragment key={pathOr(null, ['row', 'original', 'Id'], row)}>
            <DatePickerComponent row={row} rowValue={row.value} />
          </Fragment>
        );
      },
      Filter: false,
      width: 250,
    },
  ];

  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [hiddenColumns, setHiddenColumns] = useState(['id', 'prevRowID', 'currentRowID']);
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('Absolute');
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState([]);
  const [rowID, setPrevRow] = useState('');
  const [numOfRows, setNumOfRow] = useState(0);
  let tableData = useSelector((state) => state.pcPerformance.processor.tempStorageData.tempDataAbsolute || []);
  const isDeleteClicked = useSelector((state) => state.pcPerformance.processor.setDeleteRows);
  const isLatestEditedRowSaved = useSelector(
    (state) => state.pcPerformance.processor.latestEditedRows.isLatestEditedRowSaved,
  );
  const selectedRowIdWithoutError = useSelector(
    (state) => state.pcPerformance.processor.checkedRows.rowsIdWithoutError,
  );
  const totalRowsSelected = useSelector((state) => state.pcPerformance.processor.checkedRows.selectedRows);
  const isProcessDataSuccess = useSelector((state) => state.pcPerformance.processor.processedData.isSuccess);
  const isClearSelectedRows = useSelector((state) => state.pcPerformance.processor.clearSelectedRows);
  const tablePercentData = useSelector(
    (state) => state.pcPerformance.processor.tempStorageData.tempDataPercentage || [],
  );
  const onChangeParent = () => {
    console.log('called from child component');
  };
  console.log('Helloworld outside', totalRowsSelected);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTempData());
    dispatch(getCurrencyData());
  }, []);

  const rowData = (row) => {
    // Dispatching set and clear rows actions
    if (numOfRows < row.length) {
      const data = row[row.length - 1];
      saveToMongo(data);
    }
    setNumOfRow(row.length);
    console.log('row length ', numOfRows, row.length);
    dispatch(setSelectedRows(row));
    dispatch(clearSelectedRows(false));
    console.log('row id ', row, row.id);
    const ids = row.map((data) => {
      if (data) {
        return data.id;
      }
    });
    setSelectedRow(ids);
    console.log('ids ', ids);
  };

  const updateRowData = (row) => {
    if (rowID !== '' && row.id !== rowID) {
      const data = tableData.filter((data) => data.id === rowID);
      saveToMongo(data[0]);
    }
    setPrevRow(row.id);
    console.log(rowID);
  };

  const isNumber = (n) => {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && !isNaN(n - 0);
  };

  const handleOnChange = (val, accessor, origVal, rowID) => {
    var regex = /^\d*\.?\d*$/;
    console.log('Helloworld inside', totalRowsSelected);
    if (selectedView === 'Percentage' && !val.match(regex) && isNaN(val)) {
      if ('error'.indexOf(val) > -1) {
        enqueueSnackbar('Please resolve validation errors', { variant: 'error', preventDuplicate: true });
      } else {
        enqueueSnackbar('Please enter numbers only', { variant: 'error', preventDuplicate: true });
      }
    } else {
      dispatch(updateTableData(val, accessor, origVal, rowID));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isProcessDataSuccess != null) {
      if (isProcessDataSuccess) {
        if (selectedRowIdWithoutError.length !== totalRowsSelected.length) {
          enqueueSnackbar(
            ` Only ${selectedRowIdWithoutError.length}/${totalRowsSelected.length} rows were processed due to hard validation failures`,
            { variant: 'warning' },
          );
        } else {
          enqueueSnackbar('All rows processed', { variant: 'success' });
        }

        setSelectedRows([]);
      } else {
        enqueueSnackbar('No rows processed', { variant: 'error' });
      }
      dispatch(setProcessedDataResponse({}));
    }
  }, [isProcessDataSuccess]);

  const precise = (num) => {
    // Added regex because toFixed doesn't let user enter a decimal, hence excluded number followed by decimal
    const decimalRegex = /^\d*\.$/;
    if (!num || !isNumber(num) || String(num).match(decimalRegex)) {
      return num;
    }
    return Number(Number.parseFloat(num).toFixed(2));
  };

  console.log('table data ', tableData, isDeleteClicked);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <div>
          {/*<Button text={buttonText} type="primary" size="xSmall" handleOnClick={onToggle} />*/}
          <ToggleSwitch
            size={'xSmall'}
            optionOneText="Absolute"
            optionOneValue="Absolute"
            optionTwoText="Percentage"
            optionTwoValue="Percentage"
            selectedValue={selectedView}
            onChange={(value) => dispatch(setSelectedView(value))}
          />
        </div>
          <Table
            key={tableColumnConfig.key}
            title="Processor"
            columnConfig={processorColumnConfig}
            hiddenColumns={hiddenColumns}
            tableData={tableData}
            total={tableColumnConfig.total}
            viewSettingsEnabled={false}
            virtualisedEnabled={false}
            checkboxesEnabled
            initialSortBy={[{ id: tableColumnConfig.sortBy, desc: tableColumnConfig.sortOrder === 'descending' }]}
            onRowSelect={(row) => rowData(row)}
            rowClickEnabled={true}
            onRowClick={(row) => updateRowData(row)}
            actionBarEnabled={true}
            topPaginationEnabled={false}
            stickyColumnsEnabled
            clearAllSelectedRows={isClearSelectedRows}
            dataRequestFunction={() => null}
            actionBarActions={[
              {
                label: 'Match Fund',
                action: () => alert('Action Function Called - remember to set the action function'),
              },
              {
                label: 'Add as New ',
                action: () => alert('Action Function Called - remember to set the action function'),
              },
              {
                label: 'Delete ',
                action: () => {
                  dispatch(setDeleteRows(true));
                },
              },
              {
                label: 'Process ',
                action: () => {
                  dispatch(processCheckedData(selectedRowIdWithoutError));
                  enqueueSnackbar('Processing your data');
                },
              },
            ]}
          />
        {isDeleteClicked && <ConfirmationModal row={selectedRow} val={isDeleteClicked} />}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Processor;
```

Comment: I suspect stale enclosure and/or you are logging at the wrong time. That's a lot of code, what/where specifically should we focus?

Comment: You probably need to use `redux-connect` and mapStateToProps like `const mapStateToProps = state => ({totalRowsSelected: state.totalRowsSelected})` export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Processor)`. Also heads up, there's a lot of code in there, most people probably wont read through it all

Comment: Replace `state.totalRowsSelected` with the actual value for your redux value that you want

Comment: @Sam They are connected to store with `useSelector` and `useDispatch` react-redux hooks. No need for `connect` HOC.

Comment: if add sample code in codesandbox is better for debugging